# VSCode can't detect the installation only when installing the C# extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm on version 1.24.1. Every other installation of the other extensions I've tried has worked.

When I try to install "C# for Visual studio" I get the error "Failed to install 'ms-vscode.csharp'".

I then try to install the vsix file manually, I get this error.

```
This extension is not installable on any currently installed products
```

Here's the full log:

```
6/22/2018 6:14:59 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 6/22/2018 6:14:59 PM -
------------------------------------------- 
6/22/2018 6:14:59 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version: 
6/22/2018 6:14:59 PM - 15.6.152+ge95e4dd1ce
6/22/2018 6:14:59 PM - -------------------------------------------
6/22/2018 6:14:59 PM - Command line parameters: 
6/22/2018 6:14:59 PM -
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\Matthew\Downloads\ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2(1).vsix 
6/22/2018 6:14:59 PM -------------------------------------------- 
6/22/2018 6:14:59 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 
6/22/2018 6:14:59 PM -------------------------------------------- 
6/22/2018 6:14:59 PM - Initializing Install... 
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM - Extension Details...
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  Identifier         : csharp 
6/22/2018 6:15:03PM -   Name               : C# 
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  Author             : ms-vscode 
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  Version            : 1.15.2
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  Description        : C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp). 
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  Locale             : en-US 
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  MoreInfoURL        :  
6/22/2018 6:15:03PM -   InstalledByMSI     : False
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  SignatureState     : Unsigned 
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  Supported Products :  
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code 
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM  Version :  
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM - References         :  
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM - Signature Details...
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  Extension is not signed. 
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM -  
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM - Searching for applicable products... 
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2017
6/22/2018 6:15:03 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.    
at VSIXInstaller.App.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, Boolean
isRepairSupported, IEnumerable`1& skuData)    
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)    
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()    
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I've tried reinstalling the extension, reinstalling VScode, and restarting.
I am not behind a proxy or vpn.

The error seems to be that it can't detect visual studio code, even though it is certainly installed. This is exclusive to installing the C# extension.

Answer (score 0):

The [**OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode**](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/) seems to detect Visual Studio (Community Edition), but not .Net Core.

As seen with "[Using .NET Core in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/dotnet)", make sure you have [the .Net Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows) installed first, before installing that extension.